# how can we extract data from the HTML file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
<p style="font-size: small;" class="apple"><a name="XREF_4567_Figure1_1"></a>Assembly, 1234, 456 &amp; 789</p>
<div align="center"><image alt="apple.jpg" id="image2" source="assets/apple.jpg" />
  </div>
```

In the above html code we need to extract "Assembly, 1234, 456 & 789" and "apple.jpg"

And my python code is below

```
for line in f:
    if 'div align' in line.lower():
        #get value after class="
        myline=line.split("alt=\"")
        #get value before "
        number=myline[1].split("\"")[0]
        numbers[i].append(number)
#print(count)
#subtract oldcount to find the count of hotspots in current file
count[i].append(0)
count[i].append(len(numbers[i])-oldcount)
i = i + 1
#print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `BeautifulSoup` for that from library `bs4`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p style="font-size: small;" class="apple"><a name="XREF_4567_Figure1_1"></a>Assembly, 1234, 456 &amp; 789</p><div align="center"><image alt="apple.jpg" id="image2" source="assets/apple.jpg" />  </div>'
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(bs.find('p').get_text())
print(bs.find('image').get("alt"))
```

Comment: Hi @dallonsi I have more <p> tags in html file but I need particularly <p> tag  including <p style="font-size: small;" class="apple">

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark icon

Comment: the use `find_all` instead of `find` if you have many `<p>` tags

Comment: you can use the `class_` parameter to filter specific tags based on the class value. example: `print(soup.find('p', class_ = 'apple').get_text())`

Comment: I would suggest: `for apple in bs.find_all('p', class_="apple"):  print(apple.get_text())` if you have many `<p>` tags

Comment: How can we read the html file from folder. and saving output into csv file

Comment: That's not a precise question, I can't help that way.

Comment: @Shobha, please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem and also post new questions for different problems independent of the current question.